Free Windows alternative to ENTR?
I like ENTR for automatically running test suites when I make changes to code on Linux, but some of my code is on Windows systems.
What alternative to ENTR exists and is free (as in beer)?

You can just use PowerShell's/.NET's FileSystemWatcher in a script. E.g. you could listen to Changed and Created events from WatcherChangeTypes. It requires more typing than ENTR by default, but you could write a script that e.g. takes the path as an argument and then runs all the necessary setup, subscription and execution commands to shorten it.
